# Максимальное кол-во пользователей у Wi-Fi роутера Mikrotik hAP ac3 и аналогов

Tags: wifi, роутер

Есть необходимость установить несколько роутеров для предоставления доступа к интернету большому количеству лиц. Но я не могу найти нигде информацию сколько пользователей может единовременно обслуживать один роутер. Цель обеспечить как минимум 250 человек интернетом единовременно. Соотвественно есть вопрос.

Как много пользователей может потянуть один роутер вроде Mikrotik hAP ac3 или аналоги в том же ценовом сегменте?

Comment: Если не указано в инструкции, то это число не меньше 50. Но! Из-за особенностей протокола канал будет делиться на всех поровну, и даже при 15-20 подключениях будет заметная просадка по скорости.

Comment: @ГерманБорисов скорость значения не имеет, интернет нужен для одной простой операции

Comment: Подозреваю, что вам надо вчитываться в IEEE 802.11, IEEE 802.11n, IEEE 802.11ac и даже может быть в IEEE 802.11ax. Искать там как именно подключаются клиенты, какие таймслоты у них и вообще вот это вот всё. Я минут десять поковырялся, на поноценный ответ не набрал. Но в голове сложилось ничем не подтвержденное (кроме разговоров пользователей между собой на форумах) ощущение, что для 2.4 ГГц - около 40-50 устройств на точку доступа (на один передатчик), для 5 ГГц - около 90-110 устройств. Я бы на вашем месте купил бы какой нибудь комплект типа Ubiquiti UniFi AC Lite AP 5 pack + UniFi Controller

Comment: я вроде отвечал на этот вопрос....

Comment: @Sheridan никакого Lite - это только засрать эфир. только PROшки для вайфая больше чем на 20 человек

Answer (score 0):

Непосредственно сами стандарты протоколов связи не ограничивают количество абонентских устройств подключаемых к одной точке доступа, равно как и не регламентируют необходимость поддержки клиентскими устройствами различных стандартов оптимизации взаимодействия в многопользовательской среде. Фактически увеличение числа абонентов приводит к экспоненциальному снижению скорости передачи для единичного, одновременно работающего клиентского устройства. Аналитические данные можно посмотреть в статье [Wi-Fi высокой плотности](https://www.osp.ru/lan/2015/03/13045268). Определить сколько "потянет" клиентов роутер без четко выраженных требований к необходимой производительности единичного клиентского соединения нельзя. Если говорить о предельном количестве подключений конкретно для моделей компании MikroTik то они обусловлены искусственным ограничением в виде расширенной настройки:

[Manual:Interface/Wireless](https://wiki.mikrotik.com/wiki/Manual:Interface/Wireless#General_interface_properties):

max-station-count (integer [1..2007]; Default: 2007) = 2007 подключений.